# Combining columns with similar names by taking their averages

Tags: r

I have a data set with hundreds of columns. The names of the columns indicate different measurement types, and there are multiple columns for a single dependent variable (e.g. x1220 and x2220 column names imply that the variable "220" is measured by"x1" and "x2" methods).

I want to create a new data set including the average values for each dependent variable; therefore, I need to take the average of multiple columns with similar names (sharing the last 3 characters in their names) and create a single column in the new data set. And since I have hundreds of columns, it is very difficult to do this by hand.

Any solutions at all? Thanks in advance.

Sample data:

```
Group      X1201    X1205    X1301    X2201    X3201    X2205 ....

Group1      12.5    40.2     21.2     23.5     12.5      29.1

Group2      25.2    12.4     40.3     23.1     42.1      21.4
```

For example, I want to create a single column named "201" for all columns having 201 in the final position of their names (e.g. X1201, X2201, X3201) based on the average values of these columns and do these for all the columns with the same name endings (the same 3 characters in the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this help you

```
d %>% pivot_longer(cols=!Group,
                   names_prefix ="X.",
                   names_to = "variable") %>% 
  group_by(Group, variable) %>% 
  summarise(average = mean(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=variable,
              values_from=average)
```

Comment: Thank you! That code took the average of multiple columns and created new columns based on these values. But, the problem is that columns are named "00", "01".... So, I don't really know which column is which dependent variable.

Is there a way to keep the last 3 characters of the columns as the name of the merged column? (i.e. combining x1102, x2102, and x3102, and making this average column name "102).

Comment: It worked after removing the irrelevant columns! Thank you again!